# Writing logs on file on external sdcard on android devices

Tags: android, android-sdcard, filewriter

I have an application where I write logs on a file located on the external memory card.
This application runs on a lot of same devices, samsung galaxy S2, and when a user reports a problem we retrieve the logs through an mdm system in order to understand the cause. Every thing works really fine, but sometimes we find that there are "holes" in the log (we see the web services calls in a specific range of time but there are no logs on the file).The code I use to write the code is the following, and I really don't understand how can it be possibile

```
FileWriter filewriter = null;

            try {

                filewriter = new FileWriter(file,filewriter.append("my log message\r\n");


            } catch (Exception e) {

            } finally {
                try {
                    filewriter.close();
                    filewriter = null;
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
```

the `file` variable is initialized once per usage.

What could be the cause of the missing log records? in which direction should I investigate? The only suspect I had was not confirmed by analyzing a user's device: on the galaxy s2 running android 2.3.5 the mount point of external sdcard is "\sdcard\external_sd", this virtual path corresponds phisically to the internal memory if there is no external storage, to the external storage otherwise; So i thought that the missing records was caused due to a temporary unavailability, for any reason, of the external storage and the file was written in the internal storage, but when I took in my hands a pda where this problem occured there was no file in that path.

Does anyone had similar problems? I have no idea how this could happen

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use mount command to pull the path to physically device and give an error message when there is the wrong path.